# Creation of customized configuration window on clicking of newly created button on toolbar of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, toolbar, m2eclipse

I am working on eclipse to create 2 new buttons and if I click on that button a configuration window should open which consist simple 2 options: 1.input directory followed by browse, 2.output directory followed by browse option.
I have created 2 new buttons on toolbar by following code in plugin.xml file

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
      <actionSet
            label="Perspectives and Views Toolbar"
            visible="true"
            id="PerspectivesViewsToolbar.actionSet">
         <action
               class="perspectivesviewstoolbar.actions.ShowViewsPulldownMenuAction"
               icon="icons/views.gif"
               id="PerspectivesViewsToolbar.ViewsPulldownAction"
               label="file1"
               style="push"
               toolbarPath="PerspectivesViewsToolbar/additions"
               tooltip="Show Views">
         </action>
         <action
               class="perspectivesviewstoolbar.actions.ShowPerspectivesPulldownMenuAction"
               icon="icons/perspectives.gif"
               id="PerspectivesViewsToolbar.PerspectivesPulldownAction"
               label="file2"
               style="push"
               toolbarPath="PerspectivesViewsToolbar/additions"
               tooltip="Show Perspectives">
         </action>
      </actionSet>
   </extension>
```

It will create 2 new buttons file1 and file2 on toolbar of eclipse.
But I am stuck with opening a configuration window when I click on those buttons. I am working on eclipse indigo version.